# Configure Prometheus alerting rules combining the status of 2 different instances

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to configure into Prometheus Alerting Manager an alert that appears when the status of 2 different hosts is down.
To better explain, I have these couples of hosts (host=`instance`):

```
host1.1
host1.2

host2.1
host2.2

host3.1 
host3.2

host4.1
host4.2
...
```

and I need an alert that appears when both hosts of the SAME couple are DOWN:

```
expr = ( icmpping{instance=~"hostX1"}==0 and icmpping{instance=~"hostX2"}==0 )
```

(I know that the syntax is not correct, I just wanted to underline that `X` refers to the same number on both `icmpping`conditions)

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is perhaps to generate a label at ingestion time reflecting this logic, using [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config)

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [host]
    regex: ^(.*)\.\d+$
    target_label: host_group
```

It will generate the label you need for matching:

```
host=host1.1 => host_group=host1
host=host1.2 => host_group=host1
```

You can then use it for your alerting rules.

```
sum(icmpping) on(host_group) == 0
```

If this is not possible, you can use [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) to achieve the same (only on instant vectors)

```
sum(label_replace(icmpping,"host_group","$1","host","(.*)\._\\d+")) on(host_group) == 0
```